# How to get the name of the browser

Tags: browser-detection

We're getting an integer with : 
JFactory::getApplication()->client->browser;

Is there a way to get the browser name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser's names are set as integer `CONSTANTS` inside the `JApplicationWebClient` Class `('/libraries/joomla/application/web/client.php')`

More resources:

- **[Joomla browser detection](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/646/joomla-browser-detection)**
- [**JApplicationWebClient API**](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplicationWebClient.html)

**Getting the browser name:**

You could get the Constants of the Class in an array using PHP's **[Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php)**, like so:

```
$clientReflector = new ReflectionClass('JApplicationWebClient');
$browsers_array = $clientReflector->getConstants();
print_r($browsers_array);
```

This will result to the following:

```
Array
(
    [WINDOWS] => 1
    [WINDOWS_PHONE] => 2
    [WINDOWS_CE] => 3
    [IPHONE] => 4
    [IPAD] => 5
    [IPOD] => 6
    [MAC] => 7
    [BLACKBERRY] => 8
    [ANDROID] => 9
    [LINUX] => 10
    [TRIDENT] => 11
    [WEBKIT] => 12
    [GECKO] => 13
    [PRESTO] => 14
    [KHTML] => 15
    [AMAYA] => 16
    [IE] => 17
    [FIREFOX] => 18
    [CHROME] => 19
    [SAFARI] => 20
    [OPERA] => 21
    [ANDROIDTABLET] => 22
)
```

There is also the

```
JFactory::getApplication()->client->userAgent;
```

which would return the full user agent's string, e.g.:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/46.0